# Rails: Act_as_taggable_on vs. Rocket_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tags, ruby-on-rails-plugins, acts-as-taggable-on

Looks like [Act_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#finding-tagged-objects) is the more established gem, but [Rocket_tag](https://github.com/bradphelan/rocket_tag) is the newer and hotter one.

Which one would you recommend, and why?

Most of the posts I found that compared Rails tagging were fairly outdated, and I was wondering if anyone knew something about Rocket_tag (not much info on it out there).

Answer (score 3):

I used both.

I am very happy with act_as_taggable, but for Rails 3.1 I switched to rocket_tag.

On every project that is in rails <3.1 act_as_taggable.

Sorry, I do not have any oline resources, just my own opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of rocket_tag so I'm a bit biased. The reason I wrote rocket_tag was that I found the code for the other taggable gems to be messy and unreadable and thus hard to extend and play with. I generally use Ernie Millers excelent [Squeel](http://erniemiller.org/projects/squeel/) GEM for writing and composing database queries. Squeel is a super clean and powerful ruby DSL for putting together SQL.

If you have a need for some custom tagging query then I suggest taking a look at how rocket_tag is put together and trying to roll your own tagging analysis method.